# Apache Airflow: Using Bearer Token for SimpleHttpOperator

Tags: api, authorization, airflow

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.http_operator import SimpleHttpOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
import json

def process_source_claim_req() -> SimpleHttpOperator:
     data = {'Envelope': {'ConfigurationNumber': '#BG001', 'ProcessingMode': 'Process'}, 'Claim': {'Header': {'AmbulancePickupZip': '12345', 'BeneficiaryId': '961005801WXYZ', 'BeneficiaryZip': '12345', 'BillingZip': '12345', 'BirthDate': '01/01/1900', 'ClaimId': '26202872972300', 'DxCode01': 'M545', 'FederalTaxId': '046001309', 'IcdVersionIndicator': '0', 'MedicaidState': '', 'ProviderType': 'MC09', 'ServiceFacilityZip': '12345', 'Sex': 'U'}, 'Lines': [{'LineNumber': '1', 'Charges': '2211.48', 'DateOfService': '10/01/2020', 'EndDateOfService': '10/01/2020', 'Hcpcs': 'A0427', 'Modifier01': 'SH', 'PlaceOfService': '41', 'RenderingNpi': '1700815941', 'Units': '1.00'}, {'LineNumber': '2', 'Charges': '435.20', 'DateOfService': '10/01/2020', 'EndDateOfService': '10/01/2020', 'Hcpcs': 'A0425', 'Modifier01': 'SH', 'PlaceOfService': '41', 'RenderingNpi': '1700815941', 'Units': '12.80'}]}}

     task_func = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id='process_source_claim_req',
        http_conn_id='source_api',
        method='POST',
        data=json.dumps(data),
        headers={"Authorization": "Bearer Hqasdsdhasdhsdqigd39318",
                  "Content-Type": "application/json"}
        )

     
    
     return task_func
```

I need to connect to an api service that requires a bearer token for authorization. I have tried this exact token on postman and it has worked. However, when I try to make a post request on airflow using the SimpleHttpOperator, I get a connection time out.

Error:

> Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

**During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: `Max retries occured`**

Comment: What is the endpoint? How the connection is defined? Do you see in the log the right url you shoul post to.

Comment: Im not too familair with endpoints. the right url looks like https://.../service/process. Am I am trying to make a post request. should I add 'endpoint: '/post'' to my code?

Comment: what is the host and schema in the connection ? it seems that something wrong with the url cause if it was auth you would get 401 and not TimeOut.

Comment: my host is just my connection id, which I know is correct. and for scheme I have https

Comment: In the host you wrote the full path? https://.../service/process

Comment: Yeah I wrote the full path in airflow connections, I just didnt feel like typing it all in my question so i put the ...

Comment: can you share the full path so I'll try to reproduce it?

Comment: also, in the log, do you see... "INFO - Sending 'POST' to url: https://.../service/process" ?

Comment: The information is kinda sensitive and requies to be connnected to a certain vpn, so I can't give you the full path.

Comment: Also, yes I see the INFO -Sending POST to url. Also, thank you so much for the help so far

Comment: It says NewConnectionError

Comment: how do you use airflow ? docker-compose ? it seems like you have a problem to send request from airflow outside (not sure its a code problem)

Comment: Im running airflow thorugh docker yes

Comment: I tried testing connecting to other APIs (without need of Bearer Token), just to test my connection. It gives me a SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]. Could this be the issue for my actual API im trying to connect to aswell?

Comment: Try to add extra_options ={'verify': False} to the operator to skip ssl

Comment: Ok that worked, so it isnt an issue with my airflow setup becasue I can connect to other APIs. I have gone with a different approach and have tried to use a PythonOperator instead of the SimpleHttpOperator, and call a python functions that uses the requests library to make a post request to that api. This worked in my VScode environment, however, Airflow is saying it took too long to import my DAG (over 30 seconds). Any suggestions? Is this a good approach alternative?

Comment: it is an alternative (the SimpleHttpOperator is eventually a wrapper of it).

Comment: If I have the method="POST" do I need an endpoint parameter? And what should it be if im making a post request. Also with that alternative it is saying it takes too long to import my DAG  (over 30 seconds) and I cant run the dag in the UI

Comment: usually in the host its better to put only the domain i.e : www.api.com and in the endpoint to put the route i.e "/service/process". it give you more options to use same connection with multiple route. I need to see the whole code to figure out why it takes to long